# Mobile Redirect = Mod_Rewrite endless loop, what's wrong?

Tags: mod-rewrite, cookies, mobile

Hey all, I'm trying to redirect to a mobile site that lives in my subdirectory `m`,
To make matters worse I was trying to only do the redirect on the index page, and then only if a cookie (`mobile`) isn't set (so that I can send users back to the desktop site) Anyhow, my mod-rewrite gets stuck in an endless loop here's the code from .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*mobile.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera mini|IEmobile|DoCoMo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-|ipad|ipod|iphone"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|mobile safari|android"[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ m/$1 [R=307,NC,L,QSA]
```

What's making this get stuck?

also, it adds /var/www/html//var/www/html//var/www/html//var/www/html/ to the url

Comment: is this inside a per-directory (`.htaccess`/`<Directory`>) or inside a server/virtualhost context?

Comment: @ax, it's in a .htaccess (no access to httpd.conf)

Comment: please post the request headers. also, does your main site live on http://example.com/ , or on http://example.com/subdir/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how or why, but the following code is working properly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*mobile.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera mini|IEmobile|DoCoMo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-|ipad|ipod|iphone"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|mobile safari|android"[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/ [L,R=307,QSA]
```

My best guess is that the `RewriteBase` was already defined in httpd.conf and causing a conflict of some sort

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems right off the bat.

1. The constant rewriting to /var/www/html... is probably happening because you are not setting `RewriteBase` correctly.  It sounds like you need `RewriteBase /var/www/html`, presuming that is in fact the root directory of your site.
2. If I recall correctly, in per-directory rewrites (that is, rewrites in .htaccess), you do not ever have a leading slash in your path.  This is a problem on your first `RewriteCond`, in which you are checking for a leading slash before `m/`, which likely will never be there.

I'm not saying this will fix all your problems, and I don't have time at the moment to look further, but perhaps this will get you started.

Comment: [`RewriteBase` is a /URL-path/](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase), not a /local directory prefix/, so `RewriteBase /var/www/html` is definitely wrong (even though i was thinking along the same line).

Comment: @JKirchartz Have you tried it?  The RewriteBase documentation can be a little confusing because the example assumes that an Alias directive has been set, which has basically never been the case in scenarios I have worked with.

Answer (score 1):

usesIf you use [Apache Mobile Filter](http://www.apachemobilefilter.org) is easier, for example to the same think you ask:

```
#Configuration AMF Filter
#
PerlSetEnv AMFMobileHome /usr/local/AMF
PerlSetEnv AMFProductionMode true
PerlSetEnv ServerMemCached localhost:11211
PerlTransHandler +Apache2::AMFLiteDetectionFilter
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{**ENV:AMF_DEVICE_IS_MOBILE**} ^true*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.foo.org [R=301,L]
```

This is example uses AMFLiteDectionFilter module that not device repository required, but AMF supported several Device Repository such as 51Degrees.mobi, DetectRight and WURFL

Answer (score 0):

How about turning on the log and see what's really going on?

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Here's the documentation for the RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel directivies:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLog
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLogLevel